# bash readline: proxy enter key

Tags: bash, readline

When I source this script, through a readline rebind of the the enter key, I pass every line entered through a custom function, which should render normal bash behaviour - except when the current line is detected to be "special":

```
my_eval () {
    local cur_line="$READLINE_LINE"
    (...) <some special checks and actions if line matches criteria >
    # when crits DON'T match I want normal behaviour:
    eval "$cur_line"  # <- the only way?
    READLINE_LINE=""        
}
bind -x '"\C-M": "my_eval"'
```

My problem is how to get normal behaviour in such an enter handler: Is calling eval the only way or would it be possible to fall back at this point to readline's normal behaviour when enter is pressed (i.e. invoke its `accept-line` function somehow, which is normally bound to `\C-M`, according to `bind -P`)?

With the eval based solution I have to take care of handling multiline expressions manually, also redirections for interactive commands, history, display prompt and command before showing result...

Answer (score 0):

could really not find a way to invoke readline's accept-line programmatically from a script.
So I tried to mimic the behaviour manually. Far better than eval seems to be to push into history, then use fc -s to run the last command.

That works for me... okay-ish, maybe of use to someone, so I put it on:

https://github.com/axiros/readline_proxy/

Basically I push the expressions as provided within `$READLINE_LINE` into the history via `history -s` when they are deemed complete. And then run the last statement in history via `fc -s`.

[Here](https://github.com/axiros/readline_proxy/blob/master/readline_proxy) is the code.